# Подсчет числа записей в таблице

Tags: pdo, php

Добрый день! Делаю к сайту движок комментариев статей. Пишу следующий код (на PDO).

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM comments, blog
WHERE (blog.id_blog = $article_id) and (blog.id_blog = comments.code_blog)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $result->fetch();
$member = $row['count'];
```

При обновлении страничке в браузере выдается следующая ошибка:
**Fatal error:** Call to undefined method mysqli_result::setFetchMode() 
in S:\home\localhost\www\book-fan\details.php on line 98

Вопрос почему PDO не видит метод setFetchMode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я вижу из текста ошибки, вы используете **mysqli**, а не **PDO**
Покажите, как инициализируете соединение.
Попробуйте

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

И закомментируйте строчку

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Разве mysqli и PDO - это разные вещи? Я думал это одна технология работы с базой.